# renderer.setElementProperty is not working

Tags: angular

Angular2 Renderer is not working. When I try to change native element property, for example:

```
  this._renderer.setElementProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', +value);
```

and then I try to get this element current value, I see that the value didn't change.

I wonder if there is a trigger that I need to fire?

Comment: How are you trying to get this element current value? What is nativeElement looks like?

Comment: yes 
     this._elementRef.nativeElement.value returns me the old value

Comment: Could you reproduce it on this plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/1Ab69MPHVxTd77z9aOTs?p=preview?

Comment: it seems that the problem is on my side

Comment: I noticed that there are times that I try to change the element value , during tests but the value remains the same.
some one notice that?
I test a directive like in the plunker. but the directive is implement the ControlValueAccessror, and if in test I  get to the writeValue method , its not changeing the value

Comment: @yurzui, thank you very much with this plnkr you unblocked me after hours of researches/tests/screams ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Rendere2 uses `setProperty` instead of `setElementProperty`

```
this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setElementAttribute method instead

```
this._renderer.setElementAttribute(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', value);
```

Answer (score 0):

For renderer2 use `"setAttribute"` instead of "`setElementProperty`" or "`setAttribute`"

```
  this._renderer.setAttribute(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'value', value);
```